# Two column conditional sum

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function, countif

I have a table with data in two columns with three possible responses: `sim`, `nao`, and `N/A`.  I would like to to know the number of times a row contains either a `sim` or a `nao` in either column, i.e. the sum of this formula:

```
=IF(OR(A2="sim",A2="nao",B2="sim",B2="nao"),1,0)
```

In the table below it would make the result return `8`:

```
Column 1 |  Column 2
---------------------
N/A      |    Sim
---------------------
Sim      |    Sim
---------------------
Sim      |    Sim
---------------------
N/A      |    Nao
---------------------
Sim      |    Sim
---------------------
N/A      |    N/A
---------------------
Sim      |    Sim
---------------------
Sim      |    Sim
---------------------
Sim      |    Sim
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you would want to use COUNTIFS
Here is a link to an article by ablebits that explain how to use them.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/10/excel-countifs-multiple-criteria/

Answer (score 0):

add a formula = if(or()...) in the third column and then below the data range you can use =countif() function to count all cells with '1'

Answer (score 0):

I agree a helper column is the easiest approach, you could also try this:-

```
=SUM(IF((A2:A10="sim")+(B2:B10="sim")+(A2:A10="nao")+(B2:B10="nao"),1))
```

which must be entered as an array formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

The 'OR' condition is implemented as a sum. Each inner bracket which evaluates to 'TRUE' will contribute 1 to the sum of each row in an array. If the sum of the inner brackets evaluates to one or more, the IF statement will return '1' for that row.

The SUM then totals the number of rows containing a '1', to give the number of matching rows, in this case 8.

To count matching rows in the whole of the first two columns, use:-

```
=SUM(IF((A:A="sim")+(B:B="sim")+(A:A="nao")+(B:B="nao"),1))
```

[image]

The N/A above is a text string, not a #N/A error.

Comment: I'm already using a helper column that I hide after performing the calculation.  but I was looking for something a bit more elegant.
Like the for loops that I write for javascript.  I am considering writing a for loop macro with VBA but I am worried about security issues.  
I tried putting your formula into my sheet and it only returns #VALUE perhaps I am not understanding clearly what you mean by, "which must be entered as an array formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter."
Thanks for any further explanation.

Comment: @Joshua Copy & paste the formula into a cell in your spreadsheet, then instead of pressing Enter, hold down the Ctrl and Shift keys and press Enter. If you have done it correctly, you should see a set of curly brackets { } around the formula and get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, it might be restated as "how many rows am I left with if I exclude those with `N/A` in both columns of any row":

```
=COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTIFS(A:A,"N/A",B:B,"N/A")
```